# How to deal with the total differential of implicit function equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to find the total differential of $z=z(x, y)$, $z=z(x, y)$ satisfies the implicit function equation $(x+1) z-y^{2}=x^{2} f(x-z, y)$ (function $f(u, v)$ is differentiable).

```
Dt[(x + 1) z[x, y] - y^2 == x^2*f[x - z[x, y], y], z[x, y]]
```

But the above result is not in the form of $\mathrm{d} z=p(\mathrm{x}, \mathrm{y},\mathrm{z(x,y)}) \mathrm{d} \mathrm{x}+\mathrm{q}(\mathrm{x}, \mathrm{y},\mathrm{z(x,y)}) \mathrm{d} \mathrm{y}$.

What should I do to get the form I want?

**Test examples:**

$\left.\boldsymbol{d} z\right|_{(0,1)}=-\boldsymbol{d} x+2 \boldsymbol{d} y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it the following way.  Don't define the function `z` as a function of `x` and `y`:

```
expr = (x + 1) z - y^2 == x^2*f[x - z, y];
exprD = Dt@expr
```

results in

[image]

Then, solve for `Dt[z]`, collect in the variables `Dt[x]` and `Dt[y]`, and use the third argument to `Collect` to replace the `x` and `y` without replacing the values in the `Dt[x]` and `Dt[y]`:

```
Collect[
  Dt[z] /. First@Solve[exprD, Dt[z]],
  {_[x], _[y]},
  # /. {x -> 0, y -> 1} &
 ]
(* -z Dt[x] + 2 Dt[y] *)
```